# fixpoint iteration implementation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to make a program which calculates the roots of a function with the fixpoint iteration. The function is fixpoint_iteration(f,s), while f is already the fixpoint function (for example x = 2*x^2) and s is the start value. My code so far is:

```
while 1
    xn = eval(subs(g,x));
    if abs(xn-x) < 0.0000001
        disp(xn);
        break
    end
    x = xn;
end
```

The problem I have is that it often runs in an infinite loop and I don't know why and how to fix this. For example when I ask for fixpoint_iteration(@(x) x^3 + 0.3, 0), it gives me one correct root, but I can't manage to find the other roots when I use other start values because it always finds the same root and often ends in an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step through your code? Perhaps you can figure out what is going on by looking how your values change within the loop.

Comment: I already tried to observe the xn values during the while loop. When it comes to an infinite loop, they rise to infinity. But I wasn't able to fix the problem.